# Bootstrap button with image: hover not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a bootstrap button that contains an image in it and when hovering the brightness should be adjusted while everything else should remain the same. This is working in all browsers except for Firefox, anyone else encountered this problem?

CSS:

```css
.btn-framework {
      color: #333;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-color: #ccc;
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
            vertical-align: middle !important;
    }
    
    .btn-framework:hover {
        -webkit-filter: brightness(90%);
     -moz-filter: brightness(90%);
     -o-filter: brightness(90%);
     -ms-filter: brightness(90%);
     filter: brightness(90%);
    }
    
    .glyphicon-menu-right {
        float:right;
    }
    
    .framework-img {
        width: 700px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 30%;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    
    .framework-img:hover {
        width: 700px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 30% !important;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
```

```html
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-framework" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#framework1" tyle="text-align:left !important; padding-left:6px !important;">                            
               <span class="framework-title">Phase</span> 
               <img src="images/analyze/1_phase.png" class="framework-img" style="margin-top: 5px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span>
        </button>
```

Comment: What's the version and OS you're trying? I tried on macOS with Chrome `61.0.3163.100` and also with Firefox `55.0.3` and it seems to work fine in both. I even changed the values for `brightness` in the CSS and they were reflected on the page in both browsers.

Comment: Works in FF 56.0 too....

Comment: I use FF 56.0 and macOS Sierra 10.12.6. But it also doesn't work on the windows platform....